# bootstrap content slider not working properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a site using bootstrap and wanna make my slider look like this:

[image]

But mine looks like this:

[image]

```css
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
  }
 .container {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 600px !important;
    margin: auto !important;
     padding: 0;
     background-color: rgb(21, 138, 188);
}
.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right{
    background: transparent;
}
a.deposit-now {
    background-color: #e50376;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #bf053d;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #333;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <div class="slide-1">                   
            <h1>150% Welcome Bonus</h1>                 
            <p>Suspendisse ut semper enim, sed laoreet ante. Vivamus dictum arcu id mi faucibus, eget iaculis diam venenatis. Vivamus efficitur quam vitae metus mattis pretium ut ut tellus.</p>                   
            <div class="inner">                     
                <a href="" class="deposit-now">Deposit Now</a>          
                <a href="" class="terms-cond">Terms and Conditions</a>                  
            </div>              
        </div>     
      </div>
      <div class="item">

      </div>

      <div class="item">

      </div>

      <div class="item">

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the navigation buttons always be after the links as the first picture shows?
And also, is there a way to give a height to all the slides meanwhile keeping the slider responsive?

[Hope you can edit from my pen](http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/woJROE)

Comment: add your code in fiddle

Comment: Made this pen for correction  http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/woJROE
Thanks in advance

Comment: whats your issue ?

Comment: If I understood well - adding padding (e.g. 40px) to `slide-1` should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you add this to your css, then it should help you solve the issue. You can edit the values per your requirements.

```
.carousel{
  padding: 0 40px;
}
.carousel-control{
  width: 5%;
}
```

Fiddle: http://codepen.io/hunzaboy/pen/dOvaJm